# A secure serialization module like TrustedPickle with the capabilities of dill

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle, dill

Is there any Python 3 module for serialization which provides the trust relation and PKI signing capabilities of [TrustedPickle](http://trustedpickle.sourceforge.net) and can serialize instances of objects like [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill).

Comment: I'm the author of `dill`.  I don't think so.  However, you could, if you like, serialize an object to a string with `dill.dumps`, then send the string with `TrustedPickle`… then reverse the two-step process on the other side.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Cool idea, but TrustedPickle doesn't work with py3. Thinking of using HMACs with `dill`.

Comment: Yeah, didn't see you said `python 3.x`. The answer is still I don't think so.  If you find a suitable `TrustedPickle` replacement, then the above should work.